# Alter SQL Server Partition Function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

I have created a Partition Function Based on DateTime DataType, below is the Script for Partition FUnction and its corresponding partition Scheme.

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [VZDArchiveDatePartition](datetime) AS RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES
(N'2011-07-01T00:00:00.000', N'2011-08-01T00:00:00.000', N'2011-09-01T00:00:00.000',
 N'2011-10-01T00:00:00.000', N'2011-11-01T00:00:00.000', N'2011-12-01T00:00:00.000',
 N'2012-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'2012-02-01T00:00:00.000', N'2012-03-01T00:00:00.000',
 N'2012-04-01T00:00:00.000', N'2012-05-01T00:00:00.000', N'2012-06-01T00:00:00.000')
GO

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [VZDArchivePartitionScheme] AS PARTITION [VZDArchiveDatePartition] TO
([PRIMARY], [JulyFG], [AugFG], [SepFG], [OctFG], [NovFG], [DecFG], [Jan12FG],
 [Feb12FG], [Mar12FG], [Apr12FG], [May12FG], [Jun12FG])
GO
```

In the above Partition FUnction , I have used 1 month as range value.Now I would like to alter the Partition range from Month to Quarter.
Please suggest how to alter the existing function which is assigned to multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can MERGE the partitions (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186307.aspx for explanation), but given the number of partitions to be merged and multiple tables, you may be better off creating a new partition scheme and dropping and recreating the indexes using the new scheme.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- First merge two months into the third one
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION VZDArchiveDatePartition() MERGE RANGE (N'2011-08-01T00:00:00.000');
ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION VZDArchiveDatePartition() MERGE RANGE (N'2011-09-01T00:00:00.000');

-- Then shrink the files and delete them
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'AugFG' , 1) -- Ensure that 0 used, 0 estimated values are returned
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'SepFG' , 1) -- Ensure that 0 used, 0 estimated values are returned

-- At the end, deleting the files and filegroups used might be an idea
ALTER DATABASE [xxx]  REMOVE FILE      [AugFG]
ALTER DATABASE [xxx]  REMOVE FILEGROUP [AugFG]

ALTER DATABASE [xxx]  REMOVE FILE      [SepFG]
ALTER DATABASE [xxx]  REMOVE FILEGROUP [SepFG]
```